# How do I get the correct .config file for compiling the Linux kernel source specific to my hardware?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, kernel

I tried using `make defconfig` to compile the kernel, but as expected, it failed to boot. I was wondering what .config file do kernel vendors like Canonical for Ubuntu use, that the kernel is able to boot right out-of-the-box. Of course, I am still a beginner and configuring the various parameters, is a little out of my league currently.

Specifically,I am looking to load a basic "hello, world!" module to my running kernel 2.6.32.41. For that, I would need to compile kernels source against the same .config file that was used for the running kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about getting the one that's "correct for your hardware", but you can use the config that Ubuntu gives you by looking in `/boot/` for a file starting with the name `config`. There may be more than one, in which case use the command `uname -r` to tell which kernel you're currently running, and then you can use the appropriate config.

Answer (score 13):

If your running kernel was compiled with the `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` option, you can get the config in `/proc/config.gz`:

```
$ zcat /proc/config.gz >my_config
```

Copy `my_config` into your kernel build directory as `.config` and run `make config` to be prompted for configuration options that are absent from your config file (this will only happen if you are using a kernel source that is newer than your running kernel). You should then be able to compile a new kernel with the same features as your current one.

Distros typically use their own kernel configuration, where most of the drivers are compiled as modules to be dynamically loaded when the corresponding hardware is requested. Also the kernel needs to be booted with relevant boot options (like the one specifying the root filesystem). Your defconfig kernel probably failed to boot because of that.

Comment: Does `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` increase the size of the too much or why distros do not have this by default?

Answer (score 5):

***option1:***

source code of your booted  system

```
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-29;
```

this will generate .config

```
sudo make oldconfig; 
vi .config
```

***option2:***

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > my_config
```

***option3:***

```
echo /boot/config* > my_config
```

Comment: sometime .oldconfig is located inside
    cd /usr/src/kernel;

Answer (score 0):

"defconfig" is usually pegged at the commonly used hardware - x86, or x86_64, and perhaps not so recent chipset or motherboard.   Sometimes, like my Lenovo laptop, only the latest kernel source, and with enabling some config option, after googling through the bugzilla database, will it work.

Like what Jeff Welling said, to get the config in use, u can look under /boot directory.   Same for my Fedora Core too.   But if u want to compile a basic program as a "kernel module", and by that it simply means "loadable kernel module", u don't need to compile the kernel source.   U just need the kernel headers for that current version.   For example, "apt-cache search" in Ubuntu 10.04 returns several possible option:

```
linux-headers-2.6.38 - Header files related to Linux kernel, specifically,
linux-libc-dev - Linux Kernel Headers for development
```

Ubuntu normally patched the stock kernel (from kernel.org) to have their own kernel.   If u have downloaded the stock kernel, and attempt to use the /boot's config file (or sometimes u can find the currently loaded config as /proc/config.gz, like the Backtrack's Ubuntu, which is based on 10.04 LTS), then u may need to do a "make oldconfig" with the current config file named as ".config".   "make oldconfig" will then use the .config to generate a new .config that is compatible with the kernel source.